# Bitmap memory issues?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, dalvik

I have  a question regarding how Dalvik handles Bitmap data.

Say I have a class **PictureFrame**:

```
public final class PictureFrame {

    private final Bitmap mBitmap;   

    public PictureFrame(final Bitmap pBitmap) {
        this.mBitmap = pBitmap; // Loaded externally, recycle() has not been called
    }

    public final Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return this.mBitmap;
    }
}
```

Can I trust that any calls to `getBitmap()` will safely return an image that won't have been garbage collected? Additionally, if calls to `getBitmap()` are rare, will an application that uses many instances of **PictureFrame** be memory efficient? Alternatively, would it make better sense to only hold a reference to where the Bitmap is on disk, and have every call to `getBitmap()` perform a file I/O operation every time?

Comment: It would be efficient to cache the bitmap into the LruCache so you wont be in trouble of getting OutOfMemory exception

Comment: I'm not running into an `OutOfMemoryException` at this time. Do you recommend manually implementing some kind of Least Recently Used algorithm to determine which bitmaps to keep in memory? Just to elaborate, I will only be calling `getBitmap()` rarely, when the Activity holding **PictureFrame** is resumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you didnt pass null into the constructor, `getBitmap()` will never return null.

however if you did call `recycle()` on the bitmap, any subsequent attempts to use it will result in an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: That's good news! Do you have any comments regarding whether this is an inefficient implementation?

Comment: as always, that depends on context, hows the bitmap used, whats it used for, etc..

Comment: Just to clarify, I will be using possibly hundreds of **PictureFrame** instances, but only be calling `getBitmap()` once per instance when resuming an Activity.

Comment: if you have hundreds, you might be better off using a `LruCache` , look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @David Xu answer I would also recommend using [@NonNull](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm) annotation. This way you protecting yourself from having null pointer exception, by compile time testing.

```
public PictureFrame(@NonNull final Bitmap pBitmap) {
        this.mBitmap = pBitmap; // Loaded externally, recycle() has not been called
    }
```